# Делегирование событий! Как добраться до элементов ниже? (Подобие слайдера на странице)

Tags: javascript

Есть некоторая структура :

```html
<div class="team-workers"> // некий врапер
  <div class="team-workers-card"> // шаблон самого дублируемого элемента
    <div class="team-workers-card__photo"> // цель
    </div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__name"> // цель 
    </div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__socials"> // цель
    </div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__description"> // цель
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

И таких элементов "team-workers-card" допустим несколько.

Каким образом через делегирование событий мне добраться до элементов которые ниже чем "team-workers-card" ?
addEventListener вешается только на элементы которые добавлены всё таки обычным querySelector.

```js
let cardIndex = 1,
    cardList = document.querySelector('.team-workers'),
    cards = document.querySelectorAll('.team-workers-card'),

cardList.addEventListener('click',function (event) {
        for (let i = 0; i < cards.length + 1; i++) {
            if (event.target.matches('.team-workers-card') 
                && event.target == cards[i-1]){
                ***
            }
        }
});
```

Контекст всего этого неважен, но суть в том, что я бы был доволен результатом если бы только не одно но, контент этих блоков замещает всё пространство родительского .team-workers-card и я могу достучаться до него только нажав на паддинги по бокам от этого блока

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

=== Контекст ===

Но для контекста всё же опишу задачу. Мало ли, может есть другие решения. Смысл в том, чтобы кликая на эти карточки людей - это срабатывало точно так же как и с точками внизу. Навигацию по точкам я реализовал этим же методом, делегированием событий. То есть посадил addEventListener на обёртку и проверял нажал ли я на нужный элемент, но вот с этими карточками я столкнулся с проблемой , которую уже описал выше. Элементы посаженные в обёртку полностью занимают пространство и невозможно кликнуть по самой карточке, а достучаться до элементов ниже - понятия не имею как.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен `элемент.closest(селектор)` — начиная от данного элемента - ищет среди его родителей подходящий элемент. Если найдет - вернет первый найденный. Иначе - null. Т.е. если в коде ниже target будет null - условие не выполнится.

```js
let wrapper = document.querySelector('.team-workers');
let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.team-workers-card');
let bullets = document.querySelectorAll('.bullet');
let cardList = Array.from(cards);
let lastClickedIndex = 0;

wrapper.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let target = e.target.closest('.team-workers-card');
  if ( target ) {
    let index = cardList.indexOf( target );
    console.clear();
    console.log( "Кликнут номер: " + index );
    
    cards[ lastClickedIndex ].classList.remove('active');
    bullets[ lastClickedIndex ].classList.remove('active');
    
    bullets[index].classList.add('active');
    target.classList.add('active');

    lastClickedIndex = index;
  }
});
```

```css
[class^="team-workers-card__"] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 2px;
}

.team-workers-card {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #123;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.bullet {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: orange;
}

.bullet.active {
  background-color: red;
}
.team-workers-card.active {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="bullet"></div>
<div class="bullet"></div>
<div class="bullet"></div>
<div class="bullet"></div>

<div class="team-workers">
  <div class="team-workers-card">
    <div class="team-workers-card__photo"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__name"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__socials"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__description"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="team-workers-card">
    <div class="team-workers-card__photo"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__name"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__socials"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__description"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="team-workers-card">
    <div class="team-workers-card__photo"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__name"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__socials"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__description"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="team-workers-card">
    <div class="team-workers-card__photo"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__name"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__socials"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__description"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Мало ли, может есть другие решения.

Да... Например не заморачиваться с делегированием, потому что сказали, что так работает быстрее) Когда у вас всего 4 элемента (даже 1000), разница не ощутима. Вот если будет 100 000 элементов, делегирование и правда помогает сэкономить примерно 1 секунду на загрузку. Но когда уже догрузилось - при клике нет разницы в скорости срабатывания.

Поэтому (вкусовщина) в большинстве случаев предпочитаю перебор, т.к. сразу можно получить индекс кликнутого элемента:

```js
let wrapper = document.querySelector('.team-workers');
let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.team-workers-card');
let bullets = document.querySelectorAll('.bullet');
let lastClickedIndex = 0;

Array.from(cards).forEach(function(elem, index){
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.clear(); console.log(index);
    
    cards[ lastClickedIndex ].classList.remove('active');
    bullets[ lastClickedIndex ].classList.remove('active');
    
    bullets[index].classList.add('active');
    this.classList.add('active');
    
    lastClickedIndex = index;
  });
});
```

```css
[class^="team-workers-card__"] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 2px;
}

.team-workers-card {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #123;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.bullet {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: orange;
}

.bullet.active {
  background-color: red;
}
.team-workers-card.active {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="bullet"></div>
<div class="bullet"></div>
<div class="bullet"></div>
<div class="bullet"></div>

<div class="team-workers">
  <div class="team-workers-card">
    <div class="team-workers-card__photo"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__name"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__socials"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__description"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="team-workers-card">
    <div class="team-workers-card__photo"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__name"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__socials"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__description"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="team-workers-card">
    <div class="team-workers-card__photo"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__name"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__socials"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__description"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="team-workers-card">
    <div class="team-workers-card__photo"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__name"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__socials"></div>
    <div class="team-workers-card__description"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Смотрите сами, как вам удобнее)

Comment: ну подумал, что это что-то из разряда лучших практик или вроде того, почему бы и нет. Уже думал может делать какой-то кавер элемент поверх блока невидимый пробовать, чтобы по нему всегда кликалось :D Спасибо за ответ. Скопировал кусочки и хорошо